# Ubuntu 12.04 после апдейтов не грузятся Иксы

Tags: x11, настройки, ubuntu

Ubuntu 12.04 после апдейтов не грузятся Иксы пишет Cannot open display "default display". Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй при выборе загрузки выбрать загрузку с предыдущего ядра, и ещё лучше загрузиться в безопасном режиме (или как он там называется) и установить иксы по дефолту (делается в графическом режиме там вариантов не много)